# When does using RNGScope make a difference?

Tags: rcpp

In Rcpp documentation, I often find the recommendation to place `Rcpp::RNGScope scope;` before using random draws within Rcpp. I wondered what exactly this does, because I've only ever seen it described as "*ensures RNG state gets set/reset*".

Then, I tested a bit, but I can't seem to come up with an example where doing this makes any difference. I used an example from [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=AXtDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=Rcpp%20do%20I%20need%20RNGScope&source=bl&ots=eVV2s44yLb&sig=W4RwjuencPesYjY0To6A-mIvblo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aQndVM6QKoHeOIjxgEA&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Rcpp%20do%20I%20need%20RNGScope&f=false). My tests were:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector noscope() {
  Rcpp::Function rt("rt");
   return rt(5, 3);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector withscope() {
   RNGScope scope;
   Rcpp::Function rt("rt");
   return rt(5, 3);
}
```

and then

```
set.seed(45)
noscope() # [1]  0.6438 -0.6082 -1.9710 -0.1402 -0.6482

set.seed(45)
withscope() # [1]  0.6438 -0.6082 -1.9710 -0.1402 -0.6482

set.seed(45)
rt(5, 3) # [1]  0.6438 -0.6082 -1.9710 -0.1402 -0.6482
```

So, my question is twofold. First, when does RNGScope make a difference, and what exactly does it do different from not using it? Second, does anyone have a code example which shows different results with and without it?

If RNGScope was deprecated in a newer release, then I'm sorry for asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Rcpp attributes, the automagically generated interface to your code will automatically insert the appropriate construction of the `RNGScope` object -- so it's already being done for you behind the scenes in this case. For example, if you write `sourceCpp(..., verbose = TRUE)`, you'll see output like this:

```
Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_38808_timesTwo(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type x(xSEXP);
    __result = Rcpp::wrap(timesTwo(x));
    return __result;
END_RCPP
}
```

Note the automatic construction of the `RNGScope` object.

You only need to construct that object manually if you are operating outside of the realm of Rcpp attributes.

Comment: What would be an example of "operating outside the realm of Rcpp attributes"?

Comment: @Heisenberg If you write the interface boilerplate code yourself. There are also Rcpp modules, and I suspect that this is another example.

Answer (score 6):

This all becomes a little clearer once you read the *original* documentation in the [Writing R Extensions manual, Section 6.3, "Random Numbers"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Random-numbers).

All that `RNGScope` scope does is the *automagic* calls to "get" and "put" in order to keep the state of the RNG sane.

The problem with your test code, as explained by Kevin, is that it *already happens for you*.  So you can only test by going through `.Call()` by hand, in which case you *will for sure* leave the RNG in a mess if you use it *and do not* get/put properly.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very clear. And thanks for pointing to the R manual. So it is another part of the communication between R and C++ that Rcpp makes easier. So, when only using Rcpp with sourceCpp, there is no reason to declare ``RNGScope scope``?