# Is (and when) RNGScope scope needed in Rcpp code?

Tags: r, rcpp

When `RNGScope scope` is needed when using Rcpp? In general, you [need it](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Random-numbers) when using C RNG functions. In some places you can read that it is [not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487583/when-does-using-rngscope-make-a-difference) when using Rcpp, examples in [Rcpp documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) use it, some examples by Dirk Eddelbuettel [use it](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/07/14/), while others do not like [this one](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gibbs-sampler/) or [this](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2013-July/006216.html) do not. So in the end I'm confused...

When exactly is it needed and when not? Does it make a difference if I use `Rcpp::runif()`, `R::runif()`, or `R::unif_rand()`? I'm interested mostly in using Rcpp within R package rather then calling standalone code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

- *whenever* you call the RNGs of the C API of R, you need to save and later re-set state
- `RNGScope` automates this for you as it is so darn useful (and generally inexpensive)
- whenever you use Rcpp Attributes, it inserts `RNGScope` (as you can see when you turn on `verbose=TRUE`

So in general you don't need to anything manual -- unless you go *really* old school and write all code directly, foregoing the glue provided by Rcpp.

And if you use Rcpp, it doesn't matter whether you use scalar interfaces from the `R::` namespace or the vectorized `Rcpp Sugar` onces via `Rcpp::`.  `RNGScope` will be there for you.

Comment: Thanks! So maybe the examples in Rcpp vignettes should be fixed not to mention it..? I *was* expecting such answer, but the multiple examples showing something different confused me.

Comment: Pull request?  ;-)

Comment: Sure, just let me find some time for it :)

Comment: Which ones did you stumble across?  Rcpp-Introduction is older -- pre-Attributes.

Comment: For sure: Rcpp-sugar.pdf, Rcpp-FAQ.pdf I don't remember about others.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Just to clarify, does this also extend to the use of Rcpp modules? In the vignette, I noticed an explicit call to `RNGScope` for `Uniform::draw` but playing around with this example this does not seem to matter?

Comment: Not entirely sure.  If setting a seed, running Modules code to draw once or twice gets different number from setting a seed and draw in R then we have an issue.  I think this is taken care of though.