# C++ builtin random artifacts in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, random, parallel-processing, rcpp

I'm maintaining an R package named [iRF](https://github.com/cran/iRF), and a big problem is that it isn't reproducible. In other words, I cannot get the same result by setting `set.seed`. For the purpose of this question, let's focus on the function `RIT`. You don't need to figure out what it does; just look at the RNG handling part instead.

It is defined in [`R/RIT.R`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/R/RIT.R), which calls either `RIT_1class` or `RIT_2class` depending on the input type. Both `RIT_[1|2]class` functions are defined in [`src/ExportedFunctionsRIT.cpp`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/src/ExportedFunctionsRIT.cpp), which in turn calls helper functions defined in [`src/RITmain.h`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/src/RITmain.h) and [`src/RITaux.h`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/src/RITaux.h).

I'm using Rcpp attributes, so randomness in `RIT_[1|2]class` should be correctly handled by an implicit `RNGScope`, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487583/when-does-using-rngscope-make-a-difference). However, this codebase is tricky to tackle in two ways,

1. The functions [`RIT_basic`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/fc61c8d4e2739d7dd66301c5a848a444357af802/src/RITmain.h#L21) and [`RIT_minhash`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/fc61c8d4e2739d7dd66301c5a848a444357af802/src/RITmain.h#L112) use `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]`. Fortunately, the original author gives each thread a separate seed, so hopefully, I can make it deterministic with `seeds[i] = rand() * (i+1)`, yet you can tell this along isn't enough since I'm asking here.

```cpp
// Set up vector of seeds for RNG
vector<unsigned int> seeds(n_cores);
for (int i=0; i<n_cores; i++) {
  seeds[i] = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()*(i+1);
}
```

2. One of the functions, [`CreateHT`](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/fc61c8d4e2739d7dd66301c5a848a444357af802/src/RITaux.h#L31) uses `random_device rd;`. I'm not familiar with C++ but a [quick search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) reveals it generates "non-deterministic random numbers".

```cpp
void CreateHt(...) {
  // Ht is p by L
  random_device rd; //seed for Random Number Generator(RNG)
  mt19937_64 mt(rd()); //Use Mersenne Twister as RNG

  ...
    shuffle(perm.begin(), perm.end(), mt);
  ...
}
```

From my understanding, both `rand()` and `random_device` are C++'s builtin random artifacts. How can I make them respect `.Random.seed`?

Comment: I think this is addressed in WRE. If I remember correctly, it says to not use `#include <random>` as the seed for that library is platform dependent and thus results will not be reproducible on different machines/OSs. I'm assuming you are using `#include <random>` as `random_device` et al. are from that library.

Comment: My specific question is solved by [this gem](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/stl-random-shuffle/). Basically, it's a `inline int randWrapper(const int n) { return floor(unif_rand()*n); }`, followed by `std::random_shuffle(perm.begin(), perm.end(), randWrapper);`. Maybe I'll write an answer later!

Comment: Exactly --  `set.seed()` also sets the R generator. If one uses a different one from C or C++ (instead of the recommended approach of calling R's from C++) then one gets different results.  Many questions here cover this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `rand()`, c.f. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful. In particular `rand()` is not thread safe, so combining it with OpenMP will not work. However, going for C++11's `random` header is not a good idea either, since its usage is discouraged by WRE. No reason is given, but the distribution functions being implementation defined is a likely one.

Possible alternatives:

- Use R's RNG. Rcpp provides many wrapper functions in the `R` and `Rcpp` namespace. In addition `R_unif_index` is helpful for getting an *unbiased* integer within a range.
- Use the RNGs from `boost.random` provided by the BH package. Seed them with a call to R's RNG to make everything reproducible.
- Use alternative packages like [`rTRNG`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rTRNG), [`sitmo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitmo) or my own [`dqrng`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng). This is particularly helpful in the context of [parallel RNGs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dqrng/vignettes/parallel.html). [Seeding via R's RNG](https://github.com/daqana/dqrng/blob/9d2a016275dc798578aa6eb7473340ec3b77b19e/src/dqrng.cpp#L30-L34) can be used here as well.

Comment: I have decided to use your `dqrng`, but the C++ API is a little obscure. For example, I have a `NumericVector` named `weights`, from which I want to sample a random element. I read the vignettes and decided to use `weights[dqrng::dqsample_int(weights.size() - 1, 1)[0]]`, but this exact line throws a variety of errors at my face, from `non-existent physical address`, to `illegal hardware instruction`, to `illegal opcode`. Do you have some examples for the C++ interface?

Comment: There is an example in https://www.daqana.org/dqrng/articles/dqrng.html#usage-from-c. I think you are taking to many steps at once. Try to assign the results of `dqsample_int` to a vector, use that for subsetting, ....

Comment: @nalzok Are you still the maintainer of the iRF package? I saw it got removed from CRAN. Let me know if you are still interested in getting it to work with dqrng.