# Rcpp, Value Assignment Error, Meaning of SEXPREC*

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote the following code in Rcpp

```
//#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec SimulBetaBin(int K, arma::vec N){
  
  arma::vec D;

  
  Environment pkg = Environment::namespace_env("extraDistr");
  Function f = pkg["rbbinom"];

  for(int i=0; i<K; ++i){
    D[i] = f(1, N[i],  1,  1);
  }
  
  
  return  D;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to simulate a Beta Binomial Distribution.
However, when I compile the code in R, I get the following error

```
error: cannot convert 'SEXP' {aka 'SEXPREC*'} to 'double' in assignment
     D[i] = f( N[i],  1,  1);
                           ^
```

I tried to understand what a `SEXPREC*` is but I got even more confused

`What R users think of as variables or objects are symbols which are bound to a value. The value can be thought of as either a SEXP (a pointer), or the structure it points to, a SEXPREC`, what do they mean by that ??

Because I think I have to understand that first in order to solve the error.

In case

Comment: Be careful using `#include <random>`. See Ralf's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57473274/4408538

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `SEXP` back from calling a `Rcpp::Function()` object, so you need to cast it.  A modified version (also simplifying headers down to what you actually used and need) of your function follows, this one compiles for me.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
    
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec SimulBetaBin(int K, arma::vec N) {
  arma::vec D;
  Rcpp::Environment pkg = Rcpp::Environment::namespace_env("extraDistr");
  Rcpp::Function f = pkg["rbbinom"];

  for (int i=0; i<K; ++i) {
    SEXP val = f(1, N[i],  1,  1);
    D[i] = Rcpp::as<double>(val);
  }

  return  D;
}
```

*Edit:* Removed another unused header.

Comment: So, the ```SEXP``` object just stores the value, and then in order to display that value you have to cast it?? As you did with the ```Rcpp::as<double>(val);``` ??

Comment: You may want to read our [Brief Introduction to Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette. Many things are different between a compiled language like C++ and R, and a `SEXP` is a union type you cannot always directly assign.  Template programming helps in many cases, but not all.  (Also, as an aside, you may want to consider making one call `rbbinom`, not K of them.  And/or find a compiled version of `rbbinom` to work with.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spend some time in the notes!