# Why is my C++ implementation slower than the R source?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I tried to implement `charToRaw` function with Rcpp. `C_charToRaw` below is copied from the [R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/raw.c#L30-L44).

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RawVector Cpp_charToRaw(const std::string& s) {
  Rcpp::RawVector res(s.begin(), s.end());
  return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP C_charToRaw(SEXP x) {
  if (!Rf_isString(x) || LENGTH(x) == 0) {
    Rf_error("argument must be a character vector of length 1");
  }
  if (LENGTH(x) > 1) {
    Rf_warning("argument should be a character vector of length 1\nall but the first element will be ignored");
  }
  int nc = LENGTH(STRING_ELT(x, 0));
  SEXP ans = Rf_allocVector(RAWSXP, nc);
  if (nc) {
    memcpy(RAW(ans), CHAR(STRING_ELT(x, 0)), nc);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Benchmark code:

```r
x = "Test string. Test string"
bench::mark(
  Cpp_charToRaw(x),
  C_charToRaw(x),
  charToRaw(x),
  iterations = 100000
)
```

Benchmark results:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>
1 Cpp_charToRaw(x)   1.44µs   1.58µs   611480.        0B     30.6 99995     5    163.5ms < [24… <df[,…
2 C_charToRaw(x)     1.38µs   1.49µs   648339.        0B     38.9 99994     6    154.2ms < [24… <df[,…
3 charToRaw(x)     277.88ns 329.81ns  2747742.        0B     27.5 99999     1     36.4ms < [24… <df[,…
# … with 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

**Question: Why builtin `charToRaw` so fast?**

Build log:

```sh
Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>
// Cpp_charToRaw
Rcpp::RawVector Cpp_charToRaw(const std::string& s);
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_1_Cpp_charToRaw(SEXP sSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const std::string& >::type s(sSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(Cpp_charToRaw(s));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
// C_charToRaw
SEXP C_charToRaw(SEXP x);
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_1_C_charToRaw(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< SEXP >::type x(xSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(C_charToRaw(x));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/RtmpIEEIRN/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.2/sourcecpp_11646c07fffb/sourceCpp_5.so')

Cpp_charToRaw <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(s) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_Cpp_charToRaw')
C_charToRaw <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(x) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_1_C_charToRaw')

rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/RtmpIEEIRN/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.2/sourcecpp_11646c07fffb

/usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_5.so' --preclean  'test.cpp'  
g++ -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/xxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/xxx/projects/R/packages/RestRserve/tmp" -I"/home/xxx/projects/R/packages/RestRserve/tmp/../inst/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt  -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o sourceCpp_5.so test.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

### Update

Based on the answer and comments `Rcpp::RNGScope` was disables with `[[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]`.

Also little improved `Cpp_rawToChar` function:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
Rcpp::RawVector Cpp_charToRaw2(const char* s) {
  Rcpp::RawVector res(s, s + std::strlen(s));
  return res;
}
```

Updated benchmarks:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 13
  expression          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory
  <bch:expr>        <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>
1 Cpp_charToRaw(x)  448ns  506ns  1789684.        0B     35.8 99998     2     55.9ms < [24… <df[,…
2 Cpp_charToRaw2(x) 361ns  412ns  2180744.        0B     43.6 99998     2     45.9ms < [24… <df[,…
3 C_charToRaw(x)    331ns  369ns  2428416.        0B     24.3 99999     1     41.2ms < [24… <df[,…
4 charToRaw(x)      274ns  311ns  2930855.        0B     58.6 99998     2     34.1ms < [24… <df[,…
# … with 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overhead almost certainly comes from the Rcpp wrapper around your functions. As you can see from the generated code, this wrapper [sets up an RNG scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28488564/1968), which involves copying a large-ish vector of numbers (in your case this is actually unnecessary; use `[[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]` to disable it). In the case of your `Cpp_charToRaw`, the wrapper additionally needs to copy the R vector into a `std::string`, since this conversion cannot happen in-place (it could with `std::string_view`).

You can test this Rcpp overhead by benchmarking an empty Rcpp function:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP do_nothing(SEXP x) {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to omit this overhead?

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov Using `// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]` would eliminate the RNG scope.

Comment: Hi Konrad, do you know if `[[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]` also applies for disabling RNG scope within a package?

Comment: @thc It does. It's a feature of `compileAttributes()`.